# Electron - Necessary to have files within Electron package?

Tags: node.js, electron

I've installed Electron and built a small tool using it. But I find it bothersome that my files are inside the Electron package, i.e. 'Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron path-to-your-app'

Is it possible to have my working files elsewhere? Would an alias work?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a shell script that provides the correct path for running Electron apps.

(Mac)

Open Automator; create new workflow.

Left-side menu, select Utilities, then use the search to find 'Run Shell Script' and double click it to create a new workflow.

Set Shell: to /bin/sh/

Input the following:

```
{system path to >}/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/{MacOS}/Electron {system path to your electron index.html file}
```

Note the space after Electron, this separates the two parts of the command. Also, special characters, including spaces in the paths must be escaped.

Save it. To run, double-click this shell. Terminal will open, then Electron.